# How to display the data in the UI screen that are retrieved from SQLite DB in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have gone through all possible articles to get an overview of the logic behind retrieving the data from SQLite DB.But I still can't figure out the possible solution. It would be helpful if someone gives an overview of that.

For eg. I just get age as input from user and I have to display all the names matching with it.So in a table there can be n number of data matching with it.How to manage those dynamically and display that in UI?

Is there any predefined views present to handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TableLayout` but it does not  show cell borders.
Alternatively you can make a custom `ListView` and populate it with a cursor adapter.

See [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) for populating a `ListView` with `CursorAdapter`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I just went through the link you provided.All I could understand is we have to change the Cursor to a view and display that in UI. If you don't mind can you just explain what is happening over todoadapter class and after that

Comment: Actually, in the newView method we are inflating the item_todo.xml to edit the TextViews and then in the bindView method we are we are changing the Text of the TextViews to whatever we have in the cursor

Comment: Okay.Sine i am new to android programming,it's bit difficult to understand what's going on with that.So,how and when those 2 methods will be called?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace DisplayDataInUI
{
    public partial class ProductListView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Product; Integrated Security=True";

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetAllProducts", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                table.Append("<table border='1'>");
                table.Append("<tr>");
                table.Append("<th>ProductID</th><th>Name</th><th>Product Type</th><th>Price</th><th>NumberofInvoices</th>");
                table.Append("</tr>");

                if(dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        table.Append("<tr>");
                        table.Append("<td>"+ dr[0] +"</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>"+ dr[1] +"</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>"+ dr[2] +"</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>"+ dr[3] +"</td>");
                        table.Append("<td>" + dr[4] + "</td>");
                        table.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                }
                table.Append("</table>");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Data retrieval Error";
                msg += ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```